# netty in applet throws AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, sockets, applet, netty

I am using netty 3 in applet and when I start it from a browser it gives me following stacktrace in Java Console, if I run from Eclipse Applet Viewer then this issue does not happen:

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://<IP address>/crossdomain.xml, version: null]
network: Connecting http://<IP address>/crossdomain.xml with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://<IP address>:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML.privilegedConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML.check(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:150)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:113)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:771)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:541)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:210)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:227)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at org.mypackage.Myclass.connect(Client.java:80)
```

And also this

```
Exception caught: [id: 0x00498342] EXCEPTION: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "<IP address>:18090" "connect,resolve")
Exception caught: [id: 0x00498342] EXCEPTION: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

I test at local PC but specify its IP address to connect.

This is line 80 in my connect method:

```
future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

I have tried to surround it with no success

```
    AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run () {
                MyClass.connect(type, userId, secondValue);
                return null;
            }
         }
    );
```

Please, advice how can I solve it?

Comment: @fatfredyy, no, I have figured out that I need to sign it. Haven't tried it yet though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

First, I have tried to connect to `127.0.0.1`, but for that I had to install Jetty and put my applet and hmtl inside jetty. So it started to work for localhost only.

[Socket connection to originating server of an unsigned Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850497/socket-connection-to-originating-server-of-an-unsigned-java-applet)

It still didn't work for 10.x.y.z, so I had to sign applet

[Is it possible to sign a java applet for free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856552/is-is-possible-to-sign-a-java-applet-for-free)

and also to create `crossdomain.xml` in jetty like here:

[access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:8080 connect,resolve)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135138/access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-127-0-0-18080-connect-resolve)